# how to use console amixer for spdif?

Tags: linux

in alsamixer I select s/pdif 1 and unmute this, but in console command "amixer  set 'S/PDIF 1' 100% unmute" get error:
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'S/PDIF 1'.

Comment: Writing a command to program a computer to mute/unmute audio devices is programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alsamixer occasionally alters the names of some controls. Try

```
$ amixer contents
```

to get a list with the amixer controls, their proper names and their current values.

That will allow you to identify which one is the S/PDIF control. You may have to change that control in alsamixer and check for differences in the `amixer contents` output before and after to find it.

For example, on my system that control is called `IEC958 Playback Switch` in amixer.